# Alternatives to jQuery slideUp and slideDown for Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

When someone clicks on '.ui-input-note' input box, I want "#btnContainer" to appear beneath it. Working on desktop, this works perfectly:

```
HTML

        <div id="textInput"/>
        <div id="btnContainer"/>

CSS
       #btnContainer{
            height:44px;
            display: none;
        }
JS 

       $('#textInput').append(
           $('<input>').addClass('ui-input-note').attr('placeholder', 'Notes')
       );

       $('#btnContainer').append(
           $('<button id="submitBtn" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="false" data-theme="b">Save Note</button>')
       );   

        $('.ui-input-note').focus(function() {
              $( "#btnContainer" ).slideDown({
                     duration: 500 ,
                     easing: 'jswing'
              });
        });
```

But on mobile, the slideDown is slow and jumpy. I'm using a HTC One so I don't think it would run smoother on any other phone. I have tried this [plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/), which explains the 'jswing' but no joy.

So I'm trying this instead but it's not working. Would anyone have any advice or suggestions? Either to why my new function won't work, or how to get slideDown to run smoother on mobile.

```
        $('.ui-input-note').focus(function() {
                $( "#btnContainer" ).animate({
                     display: 'block',
                     left:'250px',
                     opacity:'0.5',
                     height:'150px',
                     width:'150px'
                 });
         });
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try **CSS3** ?

js:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.ui-input-note', function() {
    $('#btnContainer')addClass('large');
});
```

css:

```
#btnContainer{height:44px; display:none; transition:1s ease; -moz-transition:1s ease; -webkit-transition:1s ease; -o-transition:1s ease; -ms-transition:1s ease;}
#btnContainer.large{display:block;height:150px;}
```

hope that helped.

Comment: cheers for your help Gal but the transitions dont seem to work

Comment: does your browser support css3?

Comment: well it's up to date Chrome, so I would assume it does

Comment: can you post your html in the original question ?

Comment: Done, I generate the button and input box in jQuery and add them to two empty divs

Comment: could this be causing a problem?

Comment: yes, let me edit my answers (dynamic elements are handled differently)

Comment: It's still the same I'm afraid. The new height is applied, but not the transitions.

Comment: yup! I literally just tried that. So how could I hide my button? Opacity?

Comment: opacity will hide it but it will still be clickable... maybe just `height:0px` ?

Comment: still a little slow, but definitely better. Cheers Gal